# How to convert Cstring to TCHAR* in C++?

Tags: visual-c++

How to convert Cstring to TCHAR* in C++?

Comment: Converting to `TCHAR*` is generally not safe. Are you sure you do not want to convert to `const TCHAR*` instead?

Answer (score 0):

To convert from CString to TCHAR* simply use the GetBuffer function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Note that this can allow you to use CStrings with Win32 API functions that return strings as output parameters, as follows.

Assume that the GetStr function has the following prototype.

```
void GetStr(TCHAR *str, size_t s);
```

You can call GetStr using a CString as the first parameter as follows.

```
CString str;
GetStr(str.GetBuffer(1024), 1024);
str.ReleaseBuffer();
```

The call to GetBuffer will actually allocate enough memory to store 1024 characters.

Note that it is vital to call ReleaseBuffer. Otherwise there will be a memory leak.

Comment: Calling `ReleaseBuffer` following a `GetBuffer` is mandatory, but not for the reason you state. There will be no memory leak. The `CString` object may be in an inconsistent state, however, and the result may not be well defined. The function `ReleaseBuffer` doesn't do what its name implies; it will not release any buffers, but rather fixes up the `CString` object's internal state (such as string length, etc.).

Comment: @IInspectable That's right, but also (according to MSDN) you only have to call `ReleaseBuffer` if you've used the pointer returned by `GetBuffer` to *change* the string contents. Generally I prefer to stay away from this sort of uncertaintity altogether.